# Why does the list "aa" get a value of None

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, extend

I was experimenting with another question on Stack. I was trying to extend the list `aa` so that it contain all elements of `complete`. However, I came across this error. The following print statement prints `None`:

```
complete = [5,4,3,2,1]
aa = [1, 2]
aa = aa.extend(complete)
print aa # prints None
```

However, if I change the code a bit like so:

```
complete = [5,4,3,2,1]
aa = [1, 2]
aa.extend(complete)
print aa # prints [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

it works just fine. Why is it printing `None` in the above code?

Comment: `extend()` is an in-place method that returns None. Check out the documentation

Comment: @PeterWang Got it. I am extremely sorry for asking a duplicate. Although I did search it up, I was not able to find that post for some reason. I was also trying to make the question as clear as possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The `extend` method **does not return any value**, it simply modifies the list in place. Since you assign the return value of `extend`, which is `None`, to `aa`… well, it becomes `None`.